# Confusion between declaration and definition of a variable in C

Tags: c, variables

I am new to C and I experience some confusion between the declaration and definition of a variable. Another thing I would like to know is if the following is true:

> "Declaration appears many times and definition comes once."

Also:

```
int x;
```

Is this a declaration only? Since memory is allocated for `x` then why isn't this a definition instead of a declaration?

Comment: Where did you read this? Perhaps the author is confusing `initialization` with `declaration`?  Maybe `declaration` is meant as `extern` references?

Comment: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Difference_between_the_definition_and_declaration_of_a_variable_in_c

Comment: The info there is correct ... before "Hi I am Pruthwiraj" ... pretty much everything that person writes is wrong.

Comment: yaa @Jim that's point where i got confused..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't something you see too much in C, but it works like this:

In a header file, you can have a line like this:

```
extern int x; //declaration
```

Because of the `extern` modifier, this tells the compiler that there is an int named x *somewhere*.  The compiler doesn't allocate space for it - it just adds `int x` to the list of variables you can use.  It'll only allocate space for `x` when it sees a line like this:

```
int x; //definition
```

You can see that because only the `int x;` line changes your executable, you can have as many `extern int x;` lines as you feel like.  As long as there's only `int x;` line, everything will work like you want it to - having multiple declarations doesn't change a thing.

A better example comes from C++ (sorry if this is a C-only question - this applies to `struct`s as well, but I don't know the syntax off the top of my head):

```
class Pineapple; //declaration

Pineapple* ptr;  //this works
Pineapple pine;  //this DOES NOT work
```

This *declaration* tells the compiler that there's a class called "Pineapple".  It doesn't tell us anything about the class (how big it is, what its members are).  We can use pointers to Pineapples now, but we can't yet have instances - we don't know what makes up a Pineapple, so we don't know how much space an instance takes up.

```
class Pineapple
{
public:
    int ounces;
    char* name;
}; //definition

Pineapple* ptr;   //still works
Pineapple pine;   //this works now too!
//we can even get at member variables, 'cause we know what they are now:
pine.ounces = 17;
```

After a *definition*, we know everything about the class, so we can have instances, too.  And like the C example, you can have multiple declarations, but only one definition.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for ur response @Xavier .But  in context of extern its easy to know whts denation and whts declraion ..but suppose i have very simple programme like main() { int x ; } now here //int x ; is declarion or defination??

Comment: @AMIT  It's both.  Technically, all definitions are also declarations.  You can think of it like this:  A _declaration_ gives you a name to work with; a _definition_ gives you a name to work with as well as a memory layout.  So you can see that all definitions are declarations, 'cause definitions always give you a name (and that's all you need to be a declaration).  Now, this might be a bit of a simplification, but it works for me!

Comment: so @Xavier can i consider in case of auto,static and register storage class variable declaration is its definition??

Comment: @AMIT  With `auto` and `register`, yes for sure.  With `static`... sort of.  If you use `static` in a .c file, yes.  If you use `static` in a .h file, you'll end up with a _separate copy_ of the static variable in every .c file that includes the .h file.  I'd advise against `static` in .h files - chances are you actually want `extern`.  Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

Simply writing `int x;` at either global scope or local scope, is *both* a declaration and definition. Typically, the declaration tells the compiler "This variable will exist, at some point, under this name, so you can use it." The definition tells the compiler to actually arrange for the variable to be created - obviously this can only happen once.

Typically the way you'll use this is by putting in a header file:

```
// Foo.h
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H // make sure structs aren't redefined

extern int bar; // Declare a variable bar

#endif
```

And in a *single* source file

```
#include "foo.h"
int bar; // Define bar
```

If you were to define bar in multiple files, you would get an error; you can't create the variable twice. But you do have to tell the compiler about it in every source file you use `bar` in. Hence the `extern` declaration.

The precise semantics are defined in §6.9.2 of the C standard and can be summarized as follows:

- When a variable is declared at file scope with an initializer, it is an *external definition*. (§6.9.2/1)
- When a variable is declared at file scope without an initializer, and without a storage-class specifier or with the `static` storage-class specifier, it is a *tentative definition*. If the translation unit (file) has one or more *tentative definitions* and no *external definition*, the compiler automatically adds a true file scope declaration at the end of the translation unit, with a zero initializer. (§6.9.2/2)

What this means is that, strictly speaking, `int x;` is not a definition; but it automatically creates a definition *if and only if* there is no other definition with an initializer, and no `static` definition (this third case is undefined behavior due to linkage disagreement per §6.2.2/7)

Note that `extern int x;` is not an *external definition*. It is a declaration with an `extern` storage class specifier. As such, `extern int x;` alone does not cause a definition to be created, but if you have both:

```
extern int x;
int x;
```

Then you will end up having a definition created at some point in the file.

It is also, technically speaking, legal to do this:

```
extern int x;
int x;
int x = 42;
```

In this case, the `int x;` in the middle is superfluous and has no effect. That said, this is poor form, as it's confusing in this case where the actual definition is.

Comment: this wht i got and its quite confusing http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Difference_between_the_definition_and_declaration_of_a_variable_in_c