# Using memset with uninitialized variables

Tags: c, integer, memory-address, memset

Is this valid C code without undefined behaviour?

```
int main(){
 int a;
 memset(&a, 5, sizeof(int));

 return a;
}
```

I'm assuming this is equal to just doing `int a = 5`.

I'm trying to understand if just declaring a variable in the above example (without defining it) is enough to put it on the stack.

Comment: C doesn't have the concept of a stack. There are just variables, and stacks are implementation details.

Comment: This is not a declaration. This is a definition. It's just that initial value of it is indeterminate.

Comment: definition is doing `int a = 5`.

Comment: No. It is definition with initialization.

Comment: I'm rolling back the edit because the original question was answered; those subsequent edits invalidated the answers.

Comment: then what's the declaration? I thought `char a;` is only a declaration.

Comment: Why does it matter if it gets put on the stack? All that matters is that the result matches the specification. An optimizing compiler could translate the whole function to `return 5;`

Comment: Actually `return 0x05050505;`

Comment: I'm still confused about the above comment saying `It is definition with initialization.`? that makes no sense, this is clearly only a declaration without definition.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326789/variable-declaration-vs-definition , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration?rq=1

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Every definition in C is a declaration. Nothing can be a definition and not a declaration.

Comment: @Eric Nice. Can we have a formal definition of a declaration? :-)

Comment: @AdrianMole: It is in C 2018 6.7. Primarily, it is a list of declaration specifiers followed by a list of declarators with, optionally, initializations, followed by a semicolon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Is this valid C code without undefined behaviour?*

Yes – Once the `a` variable has been declared in a given scope (like a function or other `{ ... }` delimited block), it is valid to take its address and access the variable using that address **within that scope** (as your `memset` call does). An attempt to use that address *when that scope has ended* (i.e. is no longer 'active') will cause undefined behaviour; for example, the following is UB:

```c
int main()
{
    int* p;
    { // New scope ...
        int a;
        p = &a; // Pointer to "a" is valid HERE
    } // The scope of "a" (and its 'lifetime') ends here
    memset(p, 5, sizeof(int)); // INVALID: "p" now points to a dead (invalid) variable
}
```

However, there's a major caveat in your code sample …

> *I'm assuming this is equal to just doing int a = 5.*

There's the rub: It's assigning `5` to *each component byte* of the `a` variable, so it's doing this (assuming a 4-byte `int`):

```c
int a = 0x05050505;
```

Which is the same as:

```c
int a = 84215045;
```

Comment: sorry changed it to `char`.

Comment: @Dan don't change your question. It invalidates answers already provided.

Comment: so is it safe to say, only declaring a variable here puts it on the stack hence getting its address is valid?

Comment: @Dan Yes: Once a variable has been declared in a given scope (function or other `{ ...}` delimited block), taking its address (and using it, mostly) is valid.

Comment: @AdrianMole thanks, could you post an answer on this and I will accept it, every other answer is focusing on the data type mistake I had.

Comment: @Dan In the context of a local variable, the difference between *declaration* and *definition* is semantic. Here's a good read: [What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1410563/10871073).

Comment: Re “An attempt to use that address from *outside that scope* will cause undefined behaviour”: `void foo(void *p) { p; } int main(void) { int a; foo(&a); }` uses the address of the object named `a` outside the scope of the identifier `a`, but the behavior is fully defined.

Comment: @Eric Accurate and precise (as ever). See edit. (I blame the new font.)

Answer (score 2):

From the C Standard (7.23.6.1 The memset function)

> 2 The memset function copies the value of c (converted to an unsigned
> char) into each of the first n characters of the object pointed to by
> s.

So this call

```
memset(&a, 5, sizeof(int));
```

does not set the variable `a` equal to `5`. Internally the variable will look like

```
0x05050505
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a;
    
    memset( &a, 5, sizeof( int ) );
    
    printf( "%#x\n", ( unsigned )a );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0x5050505
```

You should use the function `memset` with integers with caution because in general it can produce a trap value. Also the result depends on how internally integers are stored starting from MSB or LSB.

P.S. You declared a variable inside a block scope with no linkage. It is also a variable definition that has automatic storage duration. As the variable explicitly was not initialized then it has an indeterminate value. You may apply the address of operator `&` to get the address of the memory extent where the variable is defined.

Comment: sorry changed it to `char`.

Comment: ok so is it safe to say, only declaring a variable here puts it on the stack hence getting its address is valid?

Comment: @Barmar It was a typo.:)

Comment: @Dan Why getting an address can not be valid? You declared (and defined) an object.

Comment: I don't know, I thought only declaring it might make passing its address to memset  UB, C is weird in that.

Comment: @Dan It's the other way around: Taking the address of a variable may force it to be put into memory.

Comment: @Dan It's always valid to get the address of a variable (unless it has the `register` modifier)

Comment: @Dan Taking an address of an object that does not have the specifier register is correct. On the other hand as the variable in your code snippet has automatic storage duration then the object  is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

That's not undefined behavior. The problem is that it doesn't what you expect.

The result of

```
memset(&a, 5, sizeof(int));
```

consists in setting to `5` each of the four bytes of your integer `a`.